# hidden highlight selection when search with * or # is active

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

Using the * key searches for the word under the cursor.

Use # to do the same, backwards.

When search is active, all instances of word appears highlighted. I want to know if is possible to remove the highlight selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hlsearch` controls this; it can be turned off with `:set nohlsearch`. This affects all sorts of searches, however, and not just <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd>. One could, theoretically, remap <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd> to do what they do and then execute `:nohlsearch` (or `:noh`) with `:nnoremap * * :noh<CR>` and `:nnoremap # # :noh<CR>` to clear highlighting every time a <kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>#</kbd> is performed. The highlighting will still flicker, but clear essentially immediately.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that option in my vimrc ^_^ thank you very much